# Should user defined literals always be consteval in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, constant-expression, user-defined-literals, consteval

If I'm not mistaken, the arguments for a [user defined literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) are always known at compile time. In C++20 you can force functions to execute at compile time using [`consteval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval) so that `throw` generates a compile time error.

```
#include <limits>

consteval int operator""_int(unsigned long long int v) {
    if (std::numeric_limits<int>::max() < v) {
        throw "out of range";
    }
    return static_cast<int>(v);
}

int main() {
    return 1'000'000'000'000_int;
}
```

```
$ g++ -std=c++20 main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:11:12:   in ‘constexpr’ expansion of ‘operator""_int(1000000000000)’
main.cpp:5:9: error: expression ‘<throw-expression>’ is not a constant expression
    5 |         throw "out of range";
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

In my experience, compile-time errors are generally preferable to run-time errors.

If other functions have to be called in the definition that are not `constexpr`, then `consteval` is obviously not an option. But apart from this case, I can't think of any reason not to use `consteval`.

Is there any other reason not to mark user defined literals as `consteval`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

User defined literals may return heap-allocated objects such as `std::string`, in which case `consteval` cannot be used because the function body is not a constant expression.

If the implementation itself can be used as a constant expression, there is no good reason not to use `consteval`.

Comment: C++20 also makes `std::string` usable at compile time. However, being `consteval` means that you cannot use the result at runtime, since compile-time allocations cannot leak into runtime code. So it's still a problem to presume that a string literal must be `consteval`.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I can think of is that it would preclude you from doing (for example):

```
int i = 42;
auto x = operator""_int (i);
```

But that is rather artificial, and you might never foresee the need.